# ...— вот(,) что я хотел сделать

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, частица-вот

Запятая нужна?

`Починить машину — вот(,) что я хотел сделать.`

`Станция метро — вот(,) где я был.`

`Слишком сложно — вот(,) почему я отказался.`

Я так понимаю, так нельзя, т. к. обобщающее слово, все дела:

`Починить машину, вот что я хотел сделать`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, ***ВОТ*** — указательная частица:

*Что я хотел сделать? Починить машину — **вот** что я хотел сделать.*

*Где я был? Станция метро — **вот** где я был.*

*Почему я отказался? Слишком сложно — **вот** почему я отказался.*

**Грамматика**: СПП, изъяснительные и обстоятельственные отношения, препозиция главной части.

Главная часть является **номинативом** (назывная конструкция).

Comment: А запятая возможна вообще в целом, не только в этих примерах?

Comment: В разговорной речи возможна, если паузу сделать меньше:  Станция метро, вот где я был.  А где ты был, я не знаю.

Comment: Я имел в виду запятую после частицы ВОТ.

Comment: Нет, там не может быть запятой, пункт  2 http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=вот&all=x

Comment: @Максим В других примерах запятая возможна. Ср.: *Вот теп**Е**рь хорошо. В**О**т, теперь хорош**О***.